# Class Dynamic Change true/ false

Tags: javascript, class, dynamic, hyperlink, navigation

What I have are multiple links in my nav bar but am having changing the ul class.
There are just two of my buttons on this page I need to change the ul class form select to current and the current to select.

```
<div class="nav">
 <ul class=" current">
    <li>
      <a href="index.php">Home</a>
      <div class="select_sub">
        <ul class="sub">
          <li></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
   </ul>

   <ul class=" select">
    <li>
      <a href="index.php?page=about_us" target="_self">About</a>
         <div class="select_sub">
            <ul class="sub">
               <li><a href="index.php?page=about_us">About Us</a></li>
               <li><a href="index.php?page=what_are_we">What are we</a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>                  
     </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Why did you remove all your javascript from the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.select').click(function () {
       $('.current').removeClass('current').addClass('select');
   });
});
```

Comment: I figured out that its not the current that I am clicking on its the select. but the rest is still not working. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have lot of syntax errors .There is no need of using quotes for `this` and you missed `;` at the end

replace

```
 $('this').removeClass('select')
```

with

```
 $(this).removeClass('select');
```

or use

```
$(this).removeClass('select'.)addClass("current");

$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.current').click(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('select'.)addClass("current");
      });
 });
```