# Class Dynamic Change

Tags: javascript, class, dynamic, hyperlink, navigation

What I have are multiple links in my nav bar but am having changing the ul class.
There are just two of my buttons on this page I need to change the ul class form select to current and the current to select.

```
div class="nav">
 <ul class=" current">
    <li>
      <a href="index.php">Home</a>
      <div class="select_sub">
        <ul class="sub">
          <li></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
   </ul>

   <ul class=" select">
    <li>
      <a href="index.php?page=about_us" target="_self">About</a>
         <div class="select_sub">
            <ul class="sub">
               <li><a href="index.php?page=about_us">About Us</a></li>
               <li><a href="index.php?page=what_are_we">What are we</a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>                  
     </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

This is the js I tried to work with, not getting any results form it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.select').click(function(){
       $('.current').removeClass('current').addClass('select');
       $(this).removeClass('select').addClass('current');

   });
});
```

Comment: dont give the answer.He posted same question just before 20 mins.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16871226/class-dynamic-change-true-false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you do:

```
$('.current').removeClass('current');
```

There won't be any elements with the class `current` - and your next statement `$('.current').addClass('select');` will not match any.

Change it to:

```
$('.current').removeClass('current').addClass('select');
```